# View's setX(), setY() and layout()

Tags: android, layout, view

What actually a contract between that methods? I thought, layout() calls setX(), but somehow, layout() stops working after calling setX().

```
view.layout(256, 256, 512, 512);
view.setX(0);
view.layout(256, 256, 512, 512);
```

but view stays on {0, 256}. Why so?

Comment: Do you mean **onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int)**?

Comment: sorry, I mean layout(int, int, int, int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 view.layout(256,256,512,512)
```

means:
Assign a size and position to a view and all of its descendants
This is the second phase of the layout mechanism. (The first is measuring). In this phase, each parent calls layout on all of its children to position them. This is typically done using the child measurements that were stored in the measure pass().
Derived classes should not override this method. Derived classes with children should override onLayout. In that method, they should call layout on each of their children.
Parameters
l
Left position, relative to parent
t
Top position, relative to parent
r
Right position, relative to parent
b
Bottom position, relative to parent

while `view.getX()`

The visual x position of this view, in pixels. This is equivalent to the translationX property plus the current left property.
Returns
The visual x position of this view, in pixels.

Hope this make sense...

Answer (score 1):

In my Understainding `child.layout(Int,int ,int ,int)` used for identify how much bigger the child is.after drawing layout.u are setting`X` position to stay there..so it staying the x position with that size.